# Android Studio breaks vector files

Tags: android-studio

My Android Studio image asset creator distorts vector files. At first I thought this was a problem with my vector files, which I created with Inkscape, but the Clip Arts that come with Android Studio have the same problem. This image shows what the Asset Studio does to its own Clip Art. [image]

Comment: Have you tried "File" > "Invalidate Caches / Restart ..." TBH I've never seen that before... I am on the latest stable 4.1.1

Comment: Tried that and other things. Not even a complete reinstall of Android Studio and/or switching to another project helped. I'm using the Snap package on Ubuntu 20.4 and am on 4.1.1 as well, if that helps. It seems to work on the canary 4.2, though.

Comment: I was on a Mac... So it may was a bug on the Linux version! Or a Halloween android... The image look very creepy xD